# Visual Studio 2012 cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm having strange intellisense error show up up even though the project works. They all deal with referenced projects.

Examples:

> cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Boolean'
>
> cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.String'
>
> Tons of warnings claiming I am not using the methods correctly. Overloads etc... Even though they work.
>
> The errors go away while debugging

This is all internal code so I can't share anything really. If I load the same project in VS 2010 I have no issues. Also other installations of 2012 had no issues.

Any general ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? Check it out from source control again so it's absolutely clean? If that doesn't work, try cutting it down so that you *have* got an example you can share.

Comment: I have cleaned and rebuilt everything. And the same project checkout works on VS 2010.

Comment: Have you installed an extension on VS?

Comment: Are you getting these errors when you build the project? To me this looks more like issues I sometimes experience with Resharper. Deleting the Resharper cache for that solution - after closing Visual Studio - usually solves that problem.

Comment: This is a clean install of VS 2012 Pro except for Update 2.

Comment: They go away when I build but then come back soon after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing VS 2012 Express on the system fixed the issue. Something must have been missing or corrupt in the .net libraries? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your the information that you have supplied, such as, working fine in VS2010, along with other installs of VS2012, It would probably be best to simply do a re-install of VS2012.

To me, it is seeming like certain links to libraries may not be referencing each other correctly for the active debugger through the intellisense.

I would also make sure that you have the most up-to-date operating system as well, as VS2012 if "fairly" new still, they may still be catching bugs that are fixed in hot fixes to the operating system (or .NET Framework).

Hope this helps!